# \MSBuild\16.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets file not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to work on an open source project in c#.

When I want to rebuild the project I get:

```
Das Projekt "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\16.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" wurde von "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.701\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" nicht in (41,3) importiert, weil die Datei nicht vorhanden ist.
```

What means in english

```
The project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\16.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.701\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" because the file is missing.
```

I the folder: 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\
I just have the subfolders:

- 15.0
- Current
- Microsoft.

Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.1.6., .Net Framework Version 4.7.03056

So I think I somehow need to upgrade MSBuild 15.0 -> 16.0.

What I have tried:

- Install Build tools for Visual studio, from: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/
- Cloning MBSBuild from https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild
  I could build the project. but no files were generated at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\16

Thank you for any help. 
    BerndGit

PS: the project I'm trying to compile ist 
https://github.com/BerndGit/Kamban/tree/feature/refactoring

**UPDATE Dotnet info**

```
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
 Version:   2.1.701
 Commit:    8cf7278aa1

Laufzeitumgebung:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.701\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.12
  Commit:  ccea2e606d

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.701 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
PM>
```

Comment: Seems like, you are mixing the build pf old-style .NET msbuild project with new sdk-style project from .NET Core

Comment: Do you have `dotnet sdk` installed? Just write `dotnet --info` in your **cmd** and tell us what the output.

Comment: @Baruch: Thanks for your comment. I have added the output to my question.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski:  I'm a C# newbie. So I cannot comment on this. I just trying to compile code, which was written by someone else. Suppose there is this mixing of technologies. This sounds to me like a more complicated issue, which is not solved by just "Install package xyz". Do you have the same impression?

Comment: @BerndGit Hi, any update for this issue? Can my workaround work or if the issue persists, share more details:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm again impressed by the high quality of the answers here. Due to familiy obligations I had not time for my hobby coding the last days. But I'll definitvly check your suggestions, will feedback, and set status in SO correctly. Most likely in the comming weekend.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: Did work. Thank you also for making that commit in GitHub. This is great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the way it imports `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` in [Kamban.csproj](https://github.com/BerndGit/Kamban/blob/feature/refactoring/KambanSolution/Kamban/Kamban.csproj):

```
<LanguageTargets>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(VisualStudioVersion)\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets</LanguageTargets>
```

According to the content of `Kamban.csproj`, it uses `$(VisualStudioVersion)` to locate `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file.It works well for VS2017 and earlier versions, but not recommended in VS2019 since the location of msbuild has **changed** in VS2019.

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/whats-new-msbuild-16-0?view=vs-2019#changed-properties): Starting in VS2019 preview, MSBuild will use "Current" instead of the major version number as part of its path.
So the `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file which you need for build process actually exists in path `...\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` instead of `...\2019\Community\MSBuild\16.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

That's why it said `file is missing` in error message, cause it tried to find the targets file from wrong path.

**As a Workaround**:

Use the `$(MSBuildToolsVersion)` instead of `$(VisualStudioVersion)` to locate the .targets file.

Open and edit the Kamban.csproj file, change the value of `LanguageTargets` to:

```
<LanguageTargets>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets</LanguageTargets>
```

Then the build engine can get correct path to find missing file.

(Note:This change works for both VS2017 and VS2019)

In addition:I've checked the open-source solution, it seems to target .net framework and .net standard, I'm not sure why this error message comes from SDK.targets, I suggest you rebuild the project in `Visual Studio IDE` or by [msbuild command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019#build-the-target).