# Getting '"Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found' when compiling with Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager

Tags: c#, build, roslyn

I have a set of projects that successfully compile and build on Visual Studio 2022.

I'd like to build them programmatically. For this purpose, I created a builder project, that makes use of `Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager`:

```
            var pc = new ProjectCollection();

            //There are a lot of properties here, these map to the msbuild CLI properties
            var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>() {

                { nameof(DTOBuildGlobalProperty.OutDir), BuildGlobalProperty.OutDir },
                { nameof(DTOBuildGlobalProperty.Platform), BuildGlobalProperty.Platform },
                { nameof(DTOBuildGlobalProperty.Configuration), BuildGlobalProperty.Configuration },
                { nameof(DTOBuildGlobalProperty.TargetFramework),$"clean,{BuildGlobalProperty.TargetFramework}"}
            };

            BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.ResetCaches();

            var bp = new BuildParameters(pc) {
                Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>() {
                    new FileLogger() { Parameters = $@"logfile={BuildGlobalProperty.OutDir}\buildme.log;append" }
                }
            };

            var brequest = new BuildRequestData(path
                , globalProperty
                , null
                , new string[] {
                    BuildGlobalPropertyTargetToBuild.Restore.ToString(),
                    BuildGlobalProperty.TargetToBuild.ToString()
                }
                , null);

            var bresult = Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, brequest);
```

This code produces a log file with the messages like:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "bin\x86\Debug\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

and the build failed, of course.

Worth to note that this code used to work with `Microsoft.Build` version `15.1.0.0` added as phisical .dll; when I attempted to upgrade my builder project to use packageReferences and added `Microsoft.Build` version `17.8.3` from Nuget, I started to notice the problem.

How can the code above be corrected, in order to work?

Notes:

I already checked similar questions and answers (like [\MSBuild\16.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017757/msbuild-16-0-bin-microsoft-csharp-targets-file-not-found)), unsuccessfully.

Comment: Are you using MSBuildLocator to register an instance of MSBuild?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski no; I don't even register any instance of MSBuild: I just call the static `Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go invoking MSBuild builds, you need to use [MSBuildLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022#use-microsoftbuildlocator) to specify the version being used. This sets various bits of environment for MSBuild that specifies where certain tasks and targets get loaded.